# excel vba FormulaArray

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I'm trying to build an advanced filter table in excel vba like in the picture below. In the last column I'm using the below array formula.

```
Worksheets("Contracts").Range("N13:N" & Worksheets("contracts").Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaArray = _
"=sum(if(invoice!$A$3:$A$2000=contracts!B13,invoice!$AA$3:$AL$2000))"
```

The issue I'm having is that it copies the formula to all cells in range without changing the cell from: contracts!B13. It stays the same. B13.

[Advanced Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MPTv.png)

Where I'm wrong?

Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: Well, what should it change to? C13, D13.. and so on?

Comment: It should change to B14, B15, B16, and so on. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
lastRow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 13 to lastRow
    Worksheets("Contracts").Range("N13:N" & i).Formula = _
    "=sum(if(invoice!$A$3:$A$2000=contracts!B" & i & ",invoice!$AA$3:$AL$2000))"
Next
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It's an array formula. I'm getting a good result by using: Worksheets("contracts").Range("N13").Copy
Worksheets("contracts").Range("N14:N" & Worksheets("contracts").Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

Comment: I don't fully understand. What issue do you run into? It can't possibly write the same formula again. O.o

Comment: If I'm using this line "Worksheets("Contracts").Range("N13:N" & i).Formula = _ " It is changing the formula, but the first cell reference is B and last row number, in my case 40 and not 13 as the first row is. But if I'm changing ".Formula" with ".FormulaArray" then I'm getting the same formula all over the cells.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Could you give me 2-3 expected results? Or even better 2-3 expected results in opposition to the results given by my answer.